# Use Word ruler with python docx

Tags: python, python-docx

Is there a way to access Word ruler option ?

For now I have manage to aligne my text using:

```
WD_TAB_ALIGNMENT.LEFT
WD_TAB_ALIGNMENT.CENTER
WD_TAB_ALIGNMENT.RIGHT
```

But I want my text to appears on the right side of the document, but left align. Like this:

```
                                                                             "text1"
                                                                             "textsample2"
```

And not like this:

```
                                                                                   "text1"
                                                                             "textsample2"
```

Comment: How do you do that using Word directly?

Comment: In the view tab, you must have the option "Ruler" checked. Then on top of your document you will have a ruler. You can then select a paragraph and by moving the little arrow on the ruler you can change the selected paragraph align start.

Comment: Okay, so you're using left-aligned tabs then. What is not working? Tab stops are set using `paragraph.paragraph_format.tab_stops`. https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#tabstops-objects

Comment: The problem is that when I use tab_stops, i have two add tabulation to the string. The ruler in word doesn't change the tabulation size. It allow you two determine where the line start and end. Like the vertical margins but just for a paragraph.

Comment: Have you looked at `paragraph.paragraph_format.left_indent`?  https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.parfmt.ParagraphFormat.left_indent

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you